# How to include a section which has code into Google Sites?

Tags: google-sites

I want to coach other people on how to write code and want to maintain a google site which will have snippets of code. How can I include sections like the ones on this stackoverflow community into my google site?

For example,
[image]

Comment: @Rob, he's trying to show an image of the styling, not the code itself. Even if he wanted to show us code, it appears he doesn't know how to do so, considering the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This nice formatting that stackoverflow uses is called [markdown](https://www.markdownguide.org/). Google sites does not appear to have support for it, so I'd suggest using something like Wordpress, which tends to be more flexible.

There is [this](https://github.com/tutts/google-sites-markdown) 2-year-old project which claims to support markdown in Google Sites, if you're stuck using that.